# Laravel Pagination links() not working

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

After doing this in my controller

```
   $activities = Package::where('attraction',1)
              ->where('hotel', 0)
              ->where('flight', 0)
              ->paginate(2);
          return view('frontend.activities',compact('activities'));
```

I added the added the for on my blade page in this fomrmat

```
@foreach($activities as $activity)
                    <div class="col-md-3 page-content-1">
                        <div class="thumb">
                            <header class="thumb-header">
                                <a class="hover-img" href="{{url('/flight-details')}}">
                                    <img src="img/new_york_at_an_angle_800x600.jpg" alt="Image Alternative text" title="new york at an angle" />
                                    <h5 class="hover-title-center">Book Now</h5>
                                </a>
                            </header>
                            <div class="thumb-caption">
                                <ul class="icon-group text-tiny text-color">
                                    <li><i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                <h5 class="thumb-title"><a class="text-darken" href="{{url('/flight-details')}}">Manhattan Skyline</a></h5>
                                <p class="mb0"><small><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> Queens (LaGuardia Airport (LGA))</small>
                                </p>
                                <p class="mb0 text-darken"><span class="text-lg lh1em text-color"><small >from</small> Free</span>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    @endforeach
```

then i added `{{ $activities->links() }}` on the page.
Whenever present the view, the links() does not display the links for the pages. 
Am i missing something or is there something that i am doing wrong

P.S : I have also tried `{{$activities->render()}}` , it did not work too.

Comment: sorry, could not solve it with that, been trying other means

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? This is kind of an official way to do what you want and I'm pretty sure this works. Do you get an error or something?

Comment: The links bar are not displayed.

Comment: Did you see my answer? It's a working solution.

Comment: If this is still an issue: what have you tried to debug the problem? Have you checked whether there should be more results than those listed on one page?

Answer (score 20):

Add the following line after "@endforeach" statement

```
{{ $activities->links('pagination::bootstrap-4') }}
```

If bulma css is used instead of bootstrap 4, customize the pagination view.

Save the following "**bulma.blade.php**" file in path "resources/views/vendor/pagination"

if the folder vendor is not present in views folder, just create it or run the following command

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-pagination
```

bulma.blade.php

```
@if ($paginator->hasPages())
    <nav class="pagination is-centered" role="navigation" aria-label="pagination">
        {{-- Previous Page Link --}}
        @if ($paginator->onFirstPage())
            <a class="pagination-previous"  disabled>Previous</a>
        @else
            <a class="pagination-previous" href="{{ $paginator->previousPageUrl() }}" rel="prev">Previous</a>
        @endif

        <ul class="pagination-list">
            {{-- Pagination Elements --}}
            @foreach ($elements as $element)
                {{-- "Three Dots" Separator --}}
                @if (is_string($element))
                    <li><span class="pagination-ellipsis">{{ $element }}</span></li>
                @endif

                {{-- Array Of Links --}}
                @if (is_array($element))
                    @foreach ($element as $page => $url)
                        @if ($page == $paginator->currentPage())
                            <li><span class="pagination-link is-current">{{ $page }}</span></li>
                        @else
                            <li><a href="{{ $url }}" class="pagination-link">{{ $page }}</a></li>
                        @endif
                    @endforeach
                @endif
            @endforeach
        </ul>

    {{-- Next Page Link --}}
    @if ($paginator->hasMorePages())
        <a class="pagination-next" href="{{ $paginator->nextPageUrl() }}" rel="next">Next page</a>
    @else
        <a class="pagination-next" disabled>Next page</a>
    @endif
@endif
```

Add the following line after "@endforeach" statement

```
{{ $activities->links('vendor.pagination.bulma') }}
```

Comment: That does not look good: controllers should not hold so much data. Additionally, why is that a `PaginateController`?

Comment: How about if you are not using bootstrap? I've disabled bootstrap and using Bulma instead.

Comment: Thanks, it worked.
Is there any other options available? Other than (pagination::bootstrap-4)

Answer (score 5):

In Laravel 5.5 if `Paginator` object has just one page, pagination links will not be displayed.

If you want to display these links anyway, you need to [customize the pagination view](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/pagination#customizing-the-pagination-view).

**1.** Run this command to copy pagination views to `resources/views/vendor/pagination`:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-pagination
```

**2.** Edit the `resources/views/vendor/pagination/default.blade.php`.

Change the very first line:

```
@if ($paginator->hasPages())
```

To:

```
@if ($paginator->count > 0)
```

Comment: this should totally be marked as the correct answer!

Answer (score 2):

Try this code in blade file:

```
{!! $activities->render() !!}
```

instead of

```
{{$activities->render()}}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to this trade https://stackoverflow.com/a/63852468/10938614
Laravel 8 has new ways and options for adding how pagination can be displayed.

Add pagination in `AppServiceProvider` class as below

```
use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;

/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    Paginator::useBootstrap();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you must have enough data to display in more that 1 page, so you must have more than 10 rows of data for the links to show, when you display 10 rows of data per page.

Comment: While true, this is more of an edge case and does not directly relate to the OPs question.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $items = $user_1->all();

    // Store records in an array
    $records = [];

    $i = 0;
    foreach($items as $item)
    {
        $records[$i][0] = $item->user_name;
        $records[$i][1] = $item->rech_mobile;
        $i++;
    }


    /****above code was replaced by the following code***/
    $items = $user_1->all()->toArray();
       /***---toArray() function used to convert object to array***/
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code. Additionally your code contains an syntax error. The last line should be a comment. Reread your answer before you post it.

Answer (score 0):

```
controller:   $users = DB::table('users')->Paginate(10);
 view file  : {{$users->links('vendor.pagination.default')}}
```

run the command:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-pagination
```

Answer (score 0):

One or some of your browser extensions maybe conflict with Tailwind Pagination rendering part. Try to turn off extensions which inspect background page.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In my case with nginx config.

I have fixed it by changing the config of nginx server. Because laravel can not get parameter 'page' thefore the links() would not be working.

in default.conf of nginx :

From:

```
location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

TO

```
location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

I hope someone can remove this error and go ahead with laravel.