# Paginate next button not getting next values

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, pagination

Next button of paginate Laravel is showing the same values as the previous page.

```
public function getInboxEmails(Request $request){
    $to_user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $Inbox = DB::table('inboxes')->where('to_user_id',$to_user_id)->where('deletedTo',0)->paginate(5);
    return view('mail',['Inbox'=>$Inbox]);
}
```

Also I noticed that next_page_url=null , prev_page_url
:
null and total=1.
AND current_page is not changing at all , always is 1

Comment: What is version laravel are you using?

Comment: @Saly im using laravel 5.4

Comment: This codes seem to be good. Can you show your blade file?

Comment: The links are there ,every thing Ok but next button are not getting new value.{{$Inbox->linsk()}} also tried {{$Inbox->render()}}

Comment: Can you try with link() method? {{ $inbox->links() }}

Comment: I tried but the same result

Answer (score 0):

These are `null` because you have only one page in results. If the query will return more than one page, these elements will contain integers instead of `null`.

Comment: Any idea how to fix it

Comment: @nesh the point was it's normal and you shouldn't fix it. But if you want to display these links anyway, you need to [modify pagination view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48284654/1227923). If you want to get pagination results as JSON, you need to modify JSON manually (if you would use 5.5 you could also use Resource class for that).